# Is there a "Scope to this" in the "Resource Manager" for VC++ 2013?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a Solution with a bunch of C++ projects. And the **Solution Explorer** has the excellent **Scope To This** that let's me focus better on a single project's files.

> **Is there equivalent functionality for the *Resource View* or maybe an add-on to achieve the same result so I can temporary scope to a single project's resources?**

**PS**: *Yes, I'm referring to old school Resource Manager (dialogs, menus, icons and such) in C++ Native Desktop Software.*

Comment: @HansPassant **And the short answer is `!`. :)** I hoped someone else noticed something I might have seriously missed or an add-on...